# exporting Intellij-Idea UI Form to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have a Java Project to do for Class. So I decided to use the Designer in Inltellij-Idea to help me get the forms and windows quickcly done, and have more time developping the application.

The problem I am facing, is the fact that the teacher uses Eclipse, So I thought that at the end of the developpement I could export my Intellij-Idea project (UI and Classes) to make it work on Eclipse.

I have no problem exporting the classes, but what about the .form files ? how do I reference them in my code, so that the eclipse project could be Buildable ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `File` | `Settings` | `GUI Designer` | `Generate GUI into`: **Java source code**.

Rebuild the project, sources will be generated from the `.form` files. Now your app can be compiled in any IDE. Don't forget to add a dependency on the `forms_rt.jar` file (bundle it with the project). It's required to compile and run your application when using GUI Designer (`IDEA_HOME\redist\forms_rt.jar`).

Comment: I checked `Java source Code` instead of binary. and now It generates `$$$setupUI$$$` that refers to functions inside `com.intellij`, the same package I can see in the /out folder. Now the part that I am not really understanding is where you say, that I must add a dependency on the `IDEA_HOME\lib\forms_rt.jar` (idea 12). Where do I add the dependency ? thank you.

Comment: In IDEA it can be added [as described in help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html). In Eclipse you would need to refer to the relevant documentation for adding `.jar` libraries to the project.

Comment: +1 for the forms_rt.jar reference. This has been driving me nuts. In my case, I was getting a runtime failure because some GUI components were not instantiated... because there was no forms_rt reference. Hope this helps someone.