# Why are the classes from forms_rt.jar not found when executing my Java application via Makefile?

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea, makefile, runtime-error

**Error when executing my java application.**

I have made a project using IntelliJ Idea, which uses forms for its UI. I want to be able to compile and execute the program via a Makefile, without having to use the IDE.  I found out that I needed to generate source code from the forms using the IDE. Also, I found out that a library called forms_rt.jar was necessary to use some lines of the source code generated.  I put this library into the compilation classpath, and compiled the program without any problem. But when I execute the jar, a message appears saying that the classes of this library are not found. (I have tried to add the class path of the library also to the manifest file).
Why aren't the library's classes found?

Comment: The Jar file specification describes [how the `Class-Path` entry in a Jar manifest is interpreted](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute).  You haven't provided enough information to inform a definitive answer, but my guess would be that you have not appreciated that entries are interpreted relative to the Jar.  If that doesn't help, then please add the relative details of filesystem layout and Jar manifest to the question.

Comment: Note also that you can include a `-classpath` on the `java -jar` command line when you launch your application.  This is more flexible than recording a classpath in the Jar manifest, because entries are interpreted relative to the filesystem root, not to the jar, and because you can choose a different classpath without modifying the Jar.  To avoid having to remember or type a classpath every time, you could consider writing a wrapper script.

Comment: Try to convert GUI forms into Java source code as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/13744911/12844632 and rebuild the project. 

Then add IDEA_HOME\lib\forms_rt.jar to the classpath and run the project from the command line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.